# select name from contacts list and display in edit text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-contacts

I want to select a contact from the contacts list and extract the name of the contact to display it in my edit text. The code for the xml file is as follows :

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/display_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/do_name_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"
    android:text="Button" />
```

The code for the MainActivity java file is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText e;
private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1;
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   }



public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String name = "";
            try {
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                        + result.toString());

                // get the contact id from the Uri
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                // query for name
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                        null);

                int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get name", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.display_name);
                e.setText(name);
                if (name.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Name not found for contact.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            break;
        }

    } else {
        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The import statements are :

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
```

I have also added the Read Contacts permission in my manifest file.

I am able to select a contact from the contacts list but the name does not appear in the edit text instead I get the toast message " Name not found for contact".
The same problem happens when fetching email too. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the value for `name` variable. You are only initializing it with empty string.

Remove the line `int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);` and add this code

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
 {
     int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
     int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
     name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
 }
```

after the line

`cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                            null);`

Comment: The above solution didn't work out. I still receive the same toast message. The name is not getting displayed in the edittext field.

Comment: just debug and see if you have any value in 'name' variable

Comment: Checked the LogCat. The message from the Log statement "Failed to get name" is shown. Also, CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index=-1 requested with a size of 1. The code seems to quite okay but then where's the error.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the code from : `int PhoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);`

to `int PhoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);`

and it worked.